# Unable to make HTTP request synchronous inside jquery done

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, asynchronous, deferred

So here is my code that I am working on to upload chunked files, I have a 2D array, each cell in the array is inturn another array which contains each files info and then followed by the actual file data, I am unable to make the http request as soon as the done function is entered, instead it is being called after the for loop is done executing. I am not able to find out a work around using IIFE and closures. Please guide. Here is the code:

```
 function chunkBinary(chunkFile){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    reader.onloadend = (function(reader)
    {
        return function()
        {
            deferred.resolve(reader.result);
        }
    })(reader);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(chunkFile);
    console.log('returning chunk data as binary');
    return deferred.promise();
 }
//changing screen and going to next step
function showUploadProgress(){
    //display the new body first with all files
    for (var i=0; i<chunk.length; i++) {
        console.log('I is: ' + i);
        console.log(chunk[i]);

        globalfileSize = chunk[i][2];
        //var fileType = chunk[i][2];
        globalfileName = chunk[i][3];
        globalChunkLen = chunk[i].length;
        var pctLoaded = 0;
        //call upload service  on chunks (chunk[i][0..3] is file info)
        for(j=4; j < chunk[i].length;j++){
            console.log('entered for-loop 2 which loops over each chunk');
            $.when(chunkBinary(chunk[i][j]))
                .done(function(result){ 
                    chunkInBinary = result;
                    var md = configOptions.data.buildPrice.dataSource['uploadEquipmentPhotosDocuments'].$d($_QUOTES.obj_quote_info.quoteNumber, $_scope.equipInfo.summary.id);
                    var chunkType = '';
                    if( j==4){ chunkType = 'First'; }
                    else if( j == globalChunkLen-1) { chunkType = 'Last'; }
                    else { chunkType = 'Middle'; }
                    var data = {"file":chunkInBinary,"chunkType":chunkType,"fileName":globalfileName,"fileSize":globalfileSize};
                    console.log('making http request for chunk');
                    return $_http(
                            {url: md, 
                             method: 'POST', 
                             data:JSON.stringify(data),
                             headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}                
                            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                    console.log(j,i);
                                    console.log('chunk sent');
                                    console.log(chunkType);
                                    console.log(globalfileName);
                                    console.log(globalfileSize);
                                    pctLoaded = (j+1)*100/(chunk[i].length -4);
                                    console.log(pctLoaded);
                            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                    console.log(j,i);
                                    console.log('chunk error');
                                    console.log(chunkType);
                                    console.log(globalfileName);
                                    console.log(globalfileSize);
                            });
                });
        }
        console.log('I incremented');
}
```

}

For what it is worth, here is a screenshot of the console after I try to upload one file.[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the `$_http()` function that you're calling?

Comment: its a custom http function that we have based on angular. That is definitly not the issue as we have used it 100s of times in other places.

Comment: Oh, so the fact that you're trying to do an http request is irrelevant? The problem is that the callback you pass to `.done()` isn't called until after the for loop ends? I would guess that's because all the promises you are creating aren't getting resolved at that stage. Try putting a `console.log()` inside the function that has `deferred.resolve(reader.result);`.

Comment: Thats throwing 'undefined is not a function' error.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have updated and added the new screenshot. I am even more confused as to what is happening now. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, I am not as of now.. Are you suggesting that I try deferred.reslve before each $_http request that I am making?

Comment: That new console picture seems to back up what I was saying, i.e., that the whole loop completes before the promises get resolved. So the solution might be to remove the for loop and instead wait until the first promise is resolved before even creating the second one.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that, I still had the second loop though, I put in a condition deferred.resolve(result) inside the done condition which is resolving my promise here and then making the call(which didnt happen though)

Comment: @nnnnnn can you please play around wth the code a little and see what I am talking about?

Comment: Your `for` loop runs to completion because it's synchronous.  THEN, some time later asynchronous operations will finish.  That's how your code is written and how Javascript will process things.  If you want only one upload to happen at a time, you will have to sequence things that way and cannot use the `for` loop the way you are using it.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you tell me how I need to modifythe for loop in that case? I still havent resolved the issue.

Comment: @NewUser - I'd be happy to help with more specific code suggestions, but I honestly don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you describe the input data structure in more detail?  And, please describe the goal (what you want it to do?).  Also, please help explain why you're doing things in chunks.